# Android : How can I keep all drawings?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view, android-drawable

I want to draw some lines in android. I use SampleView class and it's onDraw, like this :

```
private  class SampleView extends View {

        public SampleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
        }
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        p.setAntiAlias(true);
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); 
        p.setStrokeWidth(5);
        canvas.drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1, p);
            }
}
```

my x0,x1,y0,y1 changes in every time that I call sv.invalidate(). every time that it is drawing new line, **my previous line is cleared** ... but I want to keep all lines. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep track of the lines within a Path component.  Add to the path when you have a new line to draw.  Then you can draw the path within the onDraw() or clear the path when you need to for whatever reason.

[Path | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html)

One example might be something like this:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
    Path path = new Path();
    boolean isFirstPoint = true;
    for(Point point : points)
    {
        if(isFirstPoint)
        {
            isFirstPoint = false;
            path.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
        }
        else
        {
            path.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
        }
    }

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

But, of course, there are many ways to accomplish this.  The onDraw method is meant to update frequently and draws what you tell it, you have to keep state.